# Initialize ManyToMany on web environment with RESTfull API

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jpa, many-to-many

As says on [To initialize or not initialize JPA relationship mappings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715143/to-initialize-or-not-initialize-jpa-relationship-mappings) is good practice to initialize the relations on JPA mapping.

But into web architecture (Spring MVC), where the entities will be send as JSON, usually with a RESTfull API, the relations will be omitted on the serialization and it will be fetched to the server using its path (i.e employees/[id]/projects).

If we have:

```
class Employee {
    @ManyToMany //Employee owner of relation 
    protected List<Project> projects=new ArrayList<Project>(0);
 }
```

If from the client we want to update only the *Employee* name, the client send the JSON  to the server (HTTP PUT), it is deserialized and *employee.projects* will be initialized as **empty collection**. When the EntityManager save, it will update the properties (right) and the *projects* (*Employee* is owner side) **DELETING** the existing projects.

A alternative is use the  [DIY merge pattern](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/23/jpa-implementation-patterns-saving-detached-entities/). *"Instead of invoking EntityManager.merge we invoke EntityManager.find to find the existing entity and copy over the state ourselves"*. This workaround requires specific entity code on update.

What is the best way to solve it?